# Can anyone tell me what is the derivative of hadamard product

Tags: matrices, derivatives, hadamard-product

I want to know the derivative of ${\bf{(}}{{\bf{w}}^{\mathop{\rm H}\nolimits} }{\bf{A}} \odot {\bf{(}}{{\bf{w}}^{\mathop{\rm H}\nolimits} }{\bf{A)^{\bf{*}} - }}{{\bf{g}}^H}{\bf{)(}}{{\bf{A}}^H}{\bf{w}} \odot {{\bf{(}}{{\bf{A}}^{\mathop{\rm H}\nolimits} }{\bf{w)}}^{\bf{*}}}{\bf{ - g)}}$ with respect to ${\bf{w}}$, where $ \odot $ is the hadamard product, $^{\mathop{\rm H}\nolimits} $ is conjugate transpose and $^{\bf*}$ is elementwise conjugate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For convenience, define 2 new vector variables
$$\eqalign{
 x &= A^Hw &\implies x^* = A^Tw^*\cr
 y &= x^*\odot x - g &\implies y^* = y-g^*+g &\implies dy^* = dy \cr
}$$ and denote the trace/Frobenius product by a colon, i.e. 
$$\eqalign{A:B={\rm tr}(A^TB)\cr}$$
Now write the function in terms of these new variables and find its differential and gradient(s)
$$\eqalign{
 f &= y^*:y \cr\cr
df
  &= y^*:dy + y:dy^* \cr
  &= (y+y^*):dy \cr
  &= (y+y^*):x^*\odot dx \cr
  &= (y+y^*)\odot x^*:dx \cr
  &= (y+y^*)\odot x^*:A^H\,dw \cr
  &= A^*\Big((y+y^*)\odot x^*\Big):dw \cr\cr
\frac{\partial f}{\partial w} &= A^*\Big((y+y^*)\odot x^*\Big), 
&\frac{\partial f}{\partial w^*} &= A\Big((y+y^*)\odot x\Big) \cr\cr
}$$

Comment: I understand the derivation procedure， thank you very much!